# How to re-format my data response from URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

The data format I got back from URL is in this format:

```
#RES#[{"status":"Stopped \/ Idle","val":17.469444444444,"unit":"617-0003"},{"status":"Working","val":0,"unit":"617-0003"},{"status":"Headland Turning","val":0,"unit":"617-0003"},{"status":"Transport","val":0.15333333333333,"unit":"617-0003"}]
```

I want to reformat it into:

```
[
    {
    "status": "Stopped \/ Idle",
    "val": 17.469444444444},
{
    "status": "Working",
    "val": 0},
{
    "status": "Headland Turning",
    "val": 0},
{
    "status": "Transport",
    "val": 0.15333333333333}
]
```

Note:

1. Remove the beginning string `#RES#`
2. delete a field `"unit"`

Thanks.

Comment: Right... and what have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var str = '#RES#[{"status":"Stopped \/ Idle","val":17.469444444444,"unit":"617-0003"},{"status":"Working","val":0,"unit":"617-0003"},{"status":"Headland Turning","val":0,"unit":"617-0003"},{"status":"Transport","val":0.15333333333333,"unit":"617-0003"}]';
str = str.slice(5);

var json = JSON.parse(str);
console.log(json);
for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
    delete json[i].unit;
}

console.log(json);
```